# TOMAR VALOR DEL INPUT PARA USARLO EN CONSULTA MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Como se vería la consulta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZoZ.jpg)

Hola buenas.
Lo que necesito es fácil de explicar por eso solo muestro la gráfica.

En el primer formulario realizo una consulta ingresando en el input un nombre y obteniendo los datos de la BD según el mismo.

```
include 'conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['buscar']) && !empty(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
query= mysql_query($conexion, "select * from paquetes where nombre = $nombre");
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
.....
....
}
}
```

En el segundo formulario lo que deseo es: buscar entre un rango de fechas, osea por ejemplo: de: 2019-12-02 a 2019-09-06. El resultado seria: 2019-08-23. Pero este resultado debe ser del nombre ingresado en el input del formulario uno.
El problema es: Como traer el valor de ese input para usarlo en la consulta del formulario dos y mostrar en una tabla.

```
query= mysql_query($conexion, "select * from paquetes where fechas BETWEEN fecha1 AND fecha2 AND nombre = '$valorDelInput'");
```

Agradezco la ayuda. Es atendible por eso lo hago de esta forma con ejemplo. gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿por qué la etiqueta java si solo muestras php?

Comment: Buenas Daniel. Necesitamos conocer los formularios, donde están, nombres de los archivos que los contienen y a los que llaman. No podemos adivinar las cosas, por ejemplo, en el código php pones la variable $nombre, pero no está declarada ahí, por tanto estaríamos adivinando código y sería nuestra opinión, cosa poco aconsejable para ti. Pon todo el código necesario para que podamos reproducir el problema. A parte, como te indica Elena Martín, estás usando una versión obsoleta de código. Si lo estás creando de cero pásate a mysqli o PDO. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Pero los formularios entiendo que están en lugares separados? Sino podrías recuperarlo. Se me ocurre que cuando abres el segundo formulario mandes la variable del primer input y la guardes en un `<input type="hidden" />` para que al enviar el segundo formulario puedas recoger el valor de dicha variable como si fuese otro campo más.

De todas maneras te recomiendo... la librería de php mysql_ está obsoleta mejor que mires la mysqli, es decir funciones como `mysqli_query`, etc.

Lo que no se ve muy bien es cómo estás estructurando el código... si todo en el mismo archivo utilizas funciones o MVC etc.